# Why is SomeClass<? super T> not equivalent to SomeClass<T> in Java generic types?

Tags: java, generics

I noticed the specificaition for Collections.sort:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Why is the "`? super`" necessary here?  If `ClassB` extends `ClassA`, then wouldn't we have a guarantee that a `Comparator<ClassA>` would be able to compare two `ClassB` objects anyway, without the "`? super`" part?

In other words, given this code:

```
List<ClassB> list = . . . ;
Comparator<ClassA> comp = . . . ;
Collections.sort(list, comp);
```

why isn't the compiler smart enough to know that this is OK even without specifying "`? super`" for the declaration of Collections.sort()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Josh Bloch had a talk at Google I/O this year, called [Effective Java Reloaded](http://sites.google.com/site/io/effective-java-reloaded), which you may find interesting. It talks about a mnemonic called "Pecs" (producer `extends`, consumer `super`), which explains why you use `? extends T` and `? super T` in your input parameters (only; never for return types), and when to use which.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful presentation.  I think the root of my problem is the first real slide:  List<String> is not a subclass of List<Object>, in the way that String[] is a subclass of Object[].

Answer (score 6):

There's a really nice (but twisty) explanation of this in [More Fun with Wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to C#, I just learned about it a couple days ago as to why (the hard way, and then the PDC informative way).

Assume `Dog extends Animal`

`Blah<Dog>` is **not** the same as `Blah<Animal>` they have completely different type signatures even though `Dog` extends `Animal`.

For example assume a method on `Blah<T>`:

```
T Clone();
```

In `Blah<Dog>` this is `Dog Clone();` while in `Blah<Animal>` this is `Animal Clone();`.

You need a way to distinguish that the compiler can say that `Blah<Dog>` has the same public interface of `Blah<Animal>` and that's what `<? super T>` indicates - any class used as T can be reduced to its super class in terms of `Blah<? super T>`.

(In C# 4.0 this would be `Blah<out T>` I believe.)

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious to you that, in the case of `Comparator`, any ancestor of `T` would work. But the compiler doesn't know that class `Comparator` functions like that - it just needs to be told whether it should allow `<T>` or `<? super T>`.

Viewed another way, yes it's true that any `Comparator` of an ancestor would work in this case - and the way the library developer says that is to use `<? super T>`.

Comment: but it's not just obvious to me--Comparator<T> means that it has some functions that only work on objects of type T.  Since all objects of ClassB are also objects of ClassA, all the functions of Comparator<ClassA> which only work on ClassA will also work on ClassB. No human knowledge required AFAIK

Comment: @Kip: Again, see that Josh Bloch talk to see why generics was _deliberately_ designed so that Foo<Derived> does _not_ extend from Foo<Base>, even if Derived itself extends from Base. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is that the library designer wanted to give the maximum flexibility to the user of the library; this method signature for example allows you to do something like this:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
Comparator<Number> numberComparator = ...;

Collections.sort(ints, numberComparator);
```

Using the wildcard prevents you from being forced to use a `Comparator<Integer>`; the fact that the language requires a wildcard to be specified by the library designer enables him or her to either permit or restrict such use.