# Why is List<String> a subtype of List, but not of List<Object>?

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is List<Number> not a sub-type of List<Object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240316/why-is-listnumber-not-a-sub-type-of-listobject)

Isn't `String` a subtype of `Object` in Java?

Then, how come I cannot pass an object of type `List<String>` into a function that accepts `List<Object>` as a parameter? I can, though, pass such an object into a function that accepts `List` as a parameter.

Comment: This is possible when the list is covariant in its type parameter. (Covariance means: `(A <: B) => (List<A> <: List<B>)`, where `<:` is to be read as `is subtype of`, and `=>` is to be read as `implies`.) And that is only possible if the said list is immutable.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question) might help in understanding the concepts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Isn't String a subtype of Object in Java?

Yes it is, but that doesn't make `List<String>` a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Consider this example:

```
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Object> l2 = l1;  // This is a compilation error in real Java
    l2.add(new Integer(42));
    String oops = l1.get(0);
```

If (hypothetically) `List<String>` was subtype of `List<Object>`, then you'd end up assigning a `Integer` to a `String` variable in the last statement.  In short, we would have broken static type safety.

---

> I can, though, pass such an object into a function that accepts List as a parameter.

Yes, that is true.  But then you are dealing with raw types and you have to use explicit type casts when pulling objects out of the list.  For example, the above would need to be rewritten as follows:

```
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List l2 = l1;
    l2.add(new Integer(42));
    String oops = (String) l1.get(0);
```

Note that the type-cast means we've had to replace static type-safety with runtime type-safety.  (And, of course, in this case the typecast will fail at runtime because the instance has the wrong type.)

Answer (score 3):

#### You are confusing the parameterized type with the concrete type.

Given `List<T>`, `T` is the parameterized type.

`List<String>` isn't type related to `List<Object>` in any way, not anymore than `List<String>` is related to `List<Number>`. The `type` is `List<String>`, the *entire* signature is the `type`. But like with everything, there are exceptions; these are called `Wildcard Parameterized Types`.

`List<?>` is what is called an [Unbounded Wildcard Parameterized Type](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ303), it works pretty much just like a raw type, they are semantically the same, but causes more compiler warnings about unsafe casting.

`List<? extends Object>` is a bounded Wildcard Parameterized Type, and would be a type that would allow you to put anything that `extends Object` but since every class in Java `extends Object` it isn't semantically any different than the first two options.

Now they would all function the same, but they would fail `instanceof` tests, they are **not** the same types.

In other words:

```
public void myfunction(final List<Object> list) {}
```

would only accept the `type` of `List<Object>`, `List` isn't related by `type` to `List<Object>` or `List<?>`, even though they all semantically function the same.

The `type` is either `List` or `List<Object>` or `List<String>`, the inheritance chain in the `<>` is not considered when the type of the `List<T>` is concerned, until you get into [Wild Card Parameterized Types](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic4)

Here are examples:

```
Collection<?> coll = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

You can't instantiate a `new Collection<?>` only assign a concrete implementation to it.

`List<Object>` is the entire type.

Generics in Java aren't anything like the implementation in C++, other than the confusing name.

Comment: Thanks, so can `List` and `List<?>` be used interchangeablely?

Comment: @DavidFaux Absolutely not. `List` is a raw type and you can add/get any type of `Object` from it. `List<?>` is a collection of unknown objects, so you can get `Object`s from it but cannot add any to it.

Comment: @Jeffrey what you are saying isn't correct, I accidentally up voted your comment while trying to flag it. [Raw Types and Unbounded Wildcard Parameterized Types](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ303) are semantically equal in that they work the exact same way, the Wildcard version just issues more strict compiler warnings about unchecked casts.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That's true only if by warnings you mean errors. `List<?> wl = whatever(); wl.add(new Object())` will fail, but if you use a raw type it'll compile with a warning. So yes, `List` and `List<?>` are interchangable, but only in the same sense that `List<Integer>` and `List<Crayon>` are... which is to say, not.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `List<S>` **is not** a subtype of `List<T>` when `S` is a subtype of `T`. This rule provides type safety.

Let's say we allow a `List<String>` to be a subtype of `List<Object>`. Consider the following example:

```
public void foo(List<Object> objects) {
    objects.add(new Integer(42));
}

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("my string");
foo(strings); // this is not allow in java
// now strings has a string and an integer!
// what would happen if we do the following...??
String myString = strings.get(1);
```

So, forcing this provides type safety but it also has a drawback, it's less flexible. Consider the following example:

```
class MyCollection<T> {
    public void addAll(Collection<T> otherCollection) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here you have a collection of `T`'s, you want to add all items from another collection. You can't call this method with a `Collection<S>` for an `S` subtype of `T`. Ideally, this is ok  because you are only adding elements into your collection, you are not modifying the parameter collection.

To fix this, Java provides what they call "wildcards". Wildcards are a way of providing covariance/contravariance. Now consider the following using wildcards:

```
class MyCollection<T> {
     // Now we allow all types S that are a subtype of T
     public void addAll(Collection<? extends T> otherCollection) {
         ...

         otherCollection.add(new S()); // ERROR! not allowed (Here S is a subtype of T)
     }
}
```

Now, with wildcards we allow covariance in the type T and we block operations that are not type safe (for example adding an item into the collection). This way we get flexibility and type safety.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is a subtype of `Object`, yes, but that does not mean that List is a subtype of List. That's just the way Java works. You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 0):

Besides everything said above, to allow what you want, you need to explicitly declare the parameter as `List<? extends T>` (it means, accepts anything that is subclass of T including T), in this case, `List<? extends Object>` should work but `List<Object>` is limited to Object-templated lists