# Java incompatible types: child class cannot convert to parent

Tags: java

In my java code, I have an instance of a generic parent data structure being instantiated with a new instance of the generic child structure.

```java
private ParentHand<ParentCard> hand;

public Foo() {
    // Java: Incompatible types: ParentHand<ParentCard>
    // cannot be converted to ChildHand<ChildCard>();
    hand = new ChildHand<ChildCard>();
}
```

The parent interfaces are constructed as follows:

```java
public interface ParentHand<T extends ParentCard> { ... }
```

```
public interface ParentCard extends Comparable<ParentCard> {...}
```

The child interfaces are constructed as follows:

```java
public interface ChildHand<T extends ParentCard> implements ParentHand<T> { ... }
```

```java
public interface ChildCard implements ParentCard { ... }
```

I believe the above should work because of polymorphism. This is written with Java 11. Why does `Foo()` throw this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is List<String> a subtype of List, but not of List<Object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199791/why-is-liststring-a-subtype-of-list-but-not-of-listobject)

Comment: Suppose there were class `DaughterCard`, which is also a child of `ParentCard`, but is different from `ChildCard`.  You don't want to be able to write `hand.add(new DaughterCard());` as the next line of `Foo`, because `hand` references a hand of `ChildCard` objects.  But if the above compiled, you'd be able to, so you'd lose the type safety of your collection.

Comment: Have a read of Jon Skeet's answer to the duplicate question that I found.  Jon explains this beautifully.

Comment: Definitely reading through every link I can, I appreciate the link to Jon Skeet's answer as well. Thank you @DawoodibnKareem for your interpretation and how it relates to my specific "card" scenario, as it helps me understand the problem better.

Comment: No problem.  Everyone takes a while to get their head around this particular point.  All the best with your ongoing learning.

Comment: Why is it that I get the error despite having the type constraint in my generic? In order to add to a list of parents, the type added must implement the specific child card. `public interface ParentHand<T extends ChildCard>` @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: Writing `T extends ChildCard` precludes `T` from being `ParentCard`.

Comment: I should also mention that `ChildCard implements ParentCard`.