# Java Parameter and return types for enum that implements interface

Tags: java, interface, enums

After much searching I've found lots of relevant questions to normal classes, but none that really relate to enums.

This works fine:

```java
package list;

public interface Testing { 
    //treat as a tag interface.
}
```

```java
package list;

public class Foo implements Testing {
}
```

```java
package list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bar {
    public Bar(){
        List<Foo> myList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        myList.add(new Foo());
        testList(myList);
        testMethod(new Foo());
    }

    public void testMethod(Testing myInstance){
        //do nothing
    }

    public <Testing> void testList(List<Testing> myList){
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

However, my problem comes in the understanding of what happens when I try and do the same with
    `Enums`
instead of
     `Foo`

The example here is there is an interface definition that is defined as accepting an interface parameter which, in reality, is implemented by an enum that implements the interface:

I have two interfaces:

```java
public interface MyEnumInterface {
  //implemented by Enums
}
```

```java
import java.util.List;

public interface SecondInterface {
    public MyEnumInterface testMe(String myString);
    public <MyEnumInterface> List<MyEnumInterface> testingList();
    public List <MyEnumInterface> enumTestOne(String anotherString);
    public List <MyEnumInterface> enumTestTwo(String anotherString);
}
```

Two emum as follows:

```java
public enum MyEnum implements MyEnumInterface{
    VALUE_ONE,
    VALUE_TWO,
    VALUE_THREE;
}
```

```java
public enum MyEnum2 implements MyEnumInterface{
    VALUE_A,
}
```

And a test java class:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class MyClass implements SecondInterface{

    public MyClass(){
        single(testMe(""));
        enumTestOne("");
        enumTestTwo("");
    }
    public MyEnum testMe(String someParam){
            return MyEnum.VALUE_ONE;
    }

    public List<MyEnumInterface> enumTestOne(String anotherString) {
        List<MyEnum> returnL = new ArrayList<MyEnum>();
        returnL.add(MyEnum.VALUE_ONE);
        returnL.add(MyEnum.VALUE_THREE);
        return returnL;
    }

    public List<MyEnumInterface> enumTestTwo(String anotherString) {
        List<MyEnum2> returnL = new ArrayList<MyEnum2>();
        returnL.add(MyEnum2.VALUE_A);
        return returnL;
    }


    public List<MyEnum> testingList(){
        List<MyEnum> returnL = new ArrayList<MyEnum>();
        returnL.add(MyEnum.VALUE_ONE);
        returnL.add(MyEnum.VALUE_THREE);
        return returnL;
    }


    public void single(MyEnumInterface val){
        System.out.println("Value is " + val);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass clazz = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

I'm battling with the problem that the return type of enumTestOne(..) is coded as List but the interface specifies a List.  It works fine when it's an individual instance of the Enum 'MyEnum' but when it's a list of values it seems to fail with a:

> "error: method listing in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;
> required: List
> found: List
> reason: actual argument List cannot be converted to List by method invocation conversion"

I'm not sure of a way around this - I've tried adding the declaration you see above so that it reads
    `public <MyEnumInterface> List<MyEnumInterface> testingList();`
but that then gives me "warnings" about unchecked casts whilst continuing to fail

This all stems from my lack of deeper understanding around Generics and how they relate to Enums.

I've seen some interesting declarations with respect to
    `<? extends Enum<E> & SecondInterface>`
but that stretches my understanding.  Please help!

As an aside, am I correct in thinking that the generic declarations before the return class are used to specify "T" for type erosion purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow the implementing class to define which implementation of `MyEnumInterface` to use, you can specify the return type of the interface methods as a `List` of any `MyEnumInterface`.

```
public List<? extends MyEnumInterface> enumTestOne(String anotherString);
public List<? extends MyEnumInterface> enumTestTwo(String anotherString);
```

The implementations of these methods can then define the concrete return type.

```
public List<MyEnum> enumTestOne(String anotherString) {
    List<MyEnum> returnL = new ArrayList<MyEnum>();
    returnL.add(MyEnum.VALUE_ONE);
    returnL.add(MyEnum.VALUE_THREE);
    return returnL;
}

public List<MyEnum2> enumTestTwo(String anotherString) {
    List<MyEnum2> returnL = new ArrayList<MyEnum2>();
    returnL.add(MyEnum2.VALUE_A);
    return returnL;
}
```

By the way, you can do the same in "reverse" with `super`. This specifies that any type that is a supertype of the given type may be used.

```
public void addToList(List<? super MyEnum> list) {
    list.add(MyEnum.VALUE_ONE);
}

addToList(new ArrayList<MyEnum>());
addToList(new ArrayList<MyEnumInterface>());
```

#### See also

> [Java Generics (Wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)
>
> [Why is SomeClass not equivalent to SomeClass in Java generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251298/why-is-someclass-super-t-not-equivalent-to-someclasst-in-java-generic-types)

Comment: Thanks very much Anderschuller, chosen as the examples and 'see also' were spot-on: not first, but solution was entirely what I was after. Thanks.

Comment: I had completely missed that 'extends' is used within Generics to signify both sub-classes as well as sub-interfaces / interface implementations.

Answer (score 4):

Generics are `invariant` in nature. So `List<String>` is not subtype of `List<Object>`

You will have to change your method to include List of `MyEnumInterface` rather than separate enum classes.

```
public List<MyEnumInterface> enumTestOne(String anotherString) {
    List<MyEnumInterface> returnL = new ArrayList<MyEnumInterface>();//Change
    returnL.add(MyEnum.VALUE_ONE);
    returnL.add(MyEnum.VALUE_THREE);
    return returnL;
}

public List<MyEnumInterface> enumTestTwo(String anotherString) {
    List<MyEnumInterface> returnL = new ArrayList<MyEnumInterface>();//Change
    returnL.add(MyEnum2.VALUE_A);
    return returnL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation AmitD but I was really after a solution similar to what Andersschuller posted below - trying to keep the implementations to be defined as returning specifically typed instances  rather than the interface declaration.